# Laravel query join on not null

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, left-join

I have the following query join in MySQL.

```
left join the_fields as tf on 
  tf.tf_kode = x.tf_kode
  and tf.is_payed is not null
```

I tried to convert to Laravel Query Builder:

```
->leftJoin('the_fields as tf', function ($j) {
    $j->on('tf.tf_kode', '=', 'x.tf_kode');
    $j->on('tf.is_payed','!=', null);
})
```

But it shows the error `unknown column '' on clause`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any `where` filter method or `->on` method:

```
->leftJoin('the_fields as tf', function ($j) {
    $j->on('tf.tf_kode', '=', 'x.tf_kode')->whereNotNull('tf.is_payed');
    // ->where(), ->whereBetween, ->whereIn() also works
});
```

Comment: Please do not put or leave thanks & other social & meta commentary or redundancies or bad punctuation etc in posts when composing or editing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/266284